# How can I insert data into a table when I need to know the value of the foreign key from another table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have two tables:

`Customer` with the field `ID` which is auto increment and the Primary Key and

`address` with the field `customer_ID` which is a foreign key .

I have a form which asks for all of the customer info and their addresses ( can be more than 1)

I run the following two query's to update the database however I am currently inputting the value for `Customer_ID` manually to test it.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer(First_Name, Surname, Company_Name, Telephone, Alt_Telephone)VALUES('$fName', '$lName', '$cName', '$tel', '$altTel')") ;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO address(line_1, line2, town, postcode, customer_ID)VALUES('$line1', '$line2', '$town', '$post_code', '2')") ;
```

The `customer_ID` field should be the same as the current `ID` field from the customer table how can I make sure that when the address table is filled in it is doing this automatically?

Comment: try using MySQL's [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using PHP

The easiest solution to your problem would be to call [`mysql_insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) in your php-code after your first call to `mysql_query` (inserting data into your table *customer*).

This function will return the last id inserted, though you'll have to make sure that the id of *customer* is a primary key which is auto-incremented.

The value returned by `mysql_insert_id` is local to the given connection/session, even if another connection inserts a record after you did you'll get the id inserted by you.

---

#### Using MySQL

You could use the SQL-function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` as the below, just make sure that the previous sql-query ran was the insert into *customer* (as well as checking so that the id is indeed a key and *auto-incremented*).

```
-- first insert into `customer`

INSERT INTO address
  address(line_1, line2, town, postcode, customer_ID)
VALUES
  ('$line1', '$line2', '$town', '$post_code', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Same thing here as with the *php-version*, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will retrieve the last inserted ID by you.

---

You could also use a SQL feature which could be described as *SELECT INTO*, see the below snippet:

```
INSERT INTO address
 address(line_1, line2, town, postcode, customer_ID)
SELECT
  '$line1', '$line2', '$town', '$post_code', customer.id
FROM customer
WHERE <some_constraint>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

you can (1) use `mysql_insert_id()` in php, or (2) `LAST_INSERT_ID()` direct in your sql

code exempl 1:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer(First_Name, Surname, Company_Name, Telephone, Alt_Telephone)
    VALUES('$fName', '$lName', '$cName', '$tel', '$altTel')") ;
$customer_id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO address(line_1, line2, town, postcode, customer_ID) 
    VALUES('$line1', '$line2', '$town', '$post_code', {$customer_id})") ;
```

code exempl 2:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer(First_Name, Surname, Company_Name, Telephone, Alt_Telephone)
    VALUES('$fName', '$lName', '$cName', '$tel', '$altTel')") ;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO address(line_1, line2, town, postcode, customer_ID) 
    VALUES('$line1', '$line2', '$town', '$post_code', LAST_INSERT_ID())") ;
```

Comment: How does Last_Insert_ID() scale, are there race conditions?

Comment: its returned the new id of the last query run in that session, so if you insert in customer first, then it always going to be customer_id at the 2nd query (unless the first fail, then its null), if annother session inserts another row between makes no diffrent, as its the last id in your session

Comment: Good, I just wanted to be sure, it wasnt just grabbing it from the backing sequence. I havn't worked with MySQL in a long time.